# Populate pivot table with all possible value + extra column

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I'm wondering how to populate a pivot table with all possible value.

I've an Users table :

```
//users table
id | name
```

A notification_preferences table :

```
//notification_preferences table
id | name
```

And a pivot user_notification_preference

```
//user_notification_preference
id | user_id | notification_preference_id | is_enabled
```

I would like to populate my pivot table with all existing notification_preference with is_enabled value set to true, and, when I create a new notification_preference, it should sync to it with again the is_enabled value set to true.

Is there a common way to do it ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you are asking ... At what point do you want to populate the pivot table with all existing notification_preference? To set is_enabled value to true by default, you can do it at DB level setting that column with `->default(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `event closure` on your `NotificationPreference` Model, so when you create one, it creates all the necessary related records.

Something like this should work for you:

```php
class NotificationPreference extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($notificationPreference) {
            User::chunk(50, function($users) use ($notificationPreference){
                foreach($users as $user) {
                    $user->NotificationPreferences()->attach($notificationPreference->id, [
                        'is_enabled' => true
                    ]);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Notes:

- We have considered there is `belongsToMany` in `User` Model with name
  `NotificationPreferences`.
- We use `chunk` since there might be many users.

**Update:**

For previous records you can run a migration which will populate your pivot tables. Something like this:

```php
class PopulateNotificationPreferencePivotTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        NotificationPreference::chunk(50, function ($notificationPreferences) {
            foreach ($notificationPreferences as $notificationPreference) {
                User::chunk(50, function ($users) use ($notificationPreference) {
                    foreach ($users as $user) {
                        if (!$user->NotificationPreference()->where('id', $notificationPreference->id)->exists()) {
                            $user->NotificationPreference()->attach($notificationPreference->id, [
                                'is_enabled' => true
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Again we use chunk since there might be many `NotiticationPreference`.
- We check if there is already a pivot record available.